# Is Ghidra misinterpreting a function call?

Tags: c, x86, reverse-engineering, decompiling, ghidra

When analyzing the assembly listing in Ghidra, I stumbled upon this instruction:

`CALL dword ptr [EBX*0x4 + 0x402ac0]=>DAT_00402abc`

I assumed that the program was calling a function whose address was inside `DAT_00402abc`, which I initially thought it was a dword variable. Indeed, when trying to create a function in the location where `DAT_00402abc` is in, Ghidra wouldn't let me do it.

The decompiler shows to me this line of code to translate that instruction:

`(*(code *)(&int2)[iVar2])();`

So I was wondering, what does it mean and what's the program supposed to do with this call?  Is there a possibility that Ghidra totally messed up? And if so, how should I interpret that instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with Ghidra, but I can tell you how to interpret the machine instruction...

```
CALL dword ptr [EBX*0x4 + 0x402ac0]
```

There is a table of function addresses at `0x402ac0`; the EBX'th entry in that table is being called. I have no idea what `DAT_00402abc` means, but if you inspect memory in dword-sized chunks at address `0x0402ac0` you should find plausible function addresses.  [EDIT: 0x0040_2abc = 0x0040_2ac0 - 4.  I suspect this means Ghidra thinks EBX has value -1 when control reaches this point.  It may be wrong, or maybe the program has a bug.  One would expect EBX to have a *nonnegative* value when control reaches this point.]

The natural C source code corresponding to this instruction would be something like

```
extern void do_thing_zero(void);
extern void do_thing_one(void);
extern void do_thing_two(void);
extern void do_thing_three(void);

typedef void (*do_thing_ptr)(void);
const do_thing_ptr do_thing_table[4] = {
  do_thing_zero, do_thing_one, do_thing_two, do_thing_three
};

// ...

void do_thing_n(unsigned int n)
{
   if (n >= 4) abort();
   do_thing_table[n]();
}
```

If the functions in the table take arguments or return values, you'll see argument-handing code before and after the CALL instruction you quoted, but the CALL instruction itself will not change.

You would be seeing something different and much more complicated if the functions didn't all take the same set of arguments.